# Are React Hooks a good idea for "animation" / changing CSS classes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I've created a Slider with labels in react. When the user moves the Slider the numbers underneath get highlighted, I achieved it by giving the number class like this.

```
<span
   className={scaleHighlightClass[index]}
   key={index}
   ref={scaleElement}
   onClick={() => handleClickOnScale(index)}
>
```

The `scaleHighlightClass` array uses a Hook like so:

```
const [scaleHighlightClass, setScaleHighlightClass] = useState<string[]>(["selected"])
```

When the user moves the slider (which is a input with type=range) this function gets triggerd.

```
const highlightSelected = (selectedNumber) => {

   // Reset all others
   for (var i = 0; i < scaleHighlightClass.length; i++) {
      scaleHighlightClass[i] = ""
   }

   // Set the clicked/slided to as selected
   setScaleHighlightClass([...scaleHighlightClass])
}
```

It does work as expected but when using the Slider it triggers a re-render for every number it passes by. It is intended since I want to have this effect, but the question is, is this effective in terms of performance?

Is there a better way to change classes dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the current selected index in the state:

```
const [scaleHighlightIndex, setScaleHighlightIndex] = useState<number>(0)
```

The item has the selected class if it's index matches the `scaleHighlightIndex`. When you need to select another item, just pass the the current index to `setScaleHighlightIndex` directly:

```
<span
   className={index === scaleHighlightIndex ? 'selected' : ''}
   key={index}
   ref={scaleElement}
   onClick={() => setScaleHighlightIndex(index)}
>
```

You can use debounce or throttle to prevent too many re-renders, but before doing so profile, and see that you actually have a performance problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the function way to many times this way, maybe you can use debounce to decrease the number of times the code gets executed.

```
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';
const debouncedSave = debounce(() => handleClickOnScale(index), 1000);
```